# Using Grails SubmitToRemote onFailure option not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails, gsp

I'm trying to use the Grails tag `SubmitToRemote` to handle failure messages (like errors on validate domain object).

My tag submitToRemote is:

```
<g:submitToRemote
      url="[action: 'save']"
      update="[success: 'wizard', failure: 'error']"
      onFailure="onFailure(data, code)"
      name="submit"
      class="btn btn-large btn-inverse"
      value="Save"/>
```

My onFailure function is:

```
   <g:javascript>
        function onFailure(data, code){
            document.getElementById('errors').style.display = 'inline';
            $('#errors').html(data);
        }

    </g:javascript>
```

And at last, the grails action:

```
(...)
if(!plan.validate()){
    render status: 400, text: "This plan cannot be saved. Fill all fields and try again."
    return
}
```

How can I make this correctly?

Comment: How is it not working? What are you seeing? Do you see the 400 coming through in the browser?

Comment: I'm not sure what parameters I have to set in onFailure function. Passing data and code attributes don't works.

Comment: any errors in browser console?? any exceptions in IDE console? is the action being called properly?

Comment: No, no browser errors or exceptions in IDE. The Action is being called and rendering the error properly. That's weird...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps now, but can certainly help others.

I was successfully able to call and pass the message to **onFailure** method.

So this is how I do it, I set the error code and text in the controller, as below:

```
render(status: 403, text: 'Request failed to complete due to some error.')
```

Then on gsp I pulled the message using **XMLHttpRequest**:

```
<g:formRemote onFailure="onFailure(XMLHttpRequest.responseText)" ...>
```

Per my findings I saw grails wrapping up and creating below ajax for **onFailure** function.

```
error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){onFailure(XMLHttpRequest.responseText)...
```

> Grails version: 2.5.0

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I dint used onFailure but used onSuccess and implemented similar functionality.

```
<g:submitToRemote
      url="[action: 'save']"
      update="show_response"
      onSuccess="handleResponse(data, code)"
      name="submit"
      class="btn btn-large btn-inverse"
      value="Save"/>
```

show_response is your div where you would like to show the response(success/failure)

in controller or service

```
def save()  {
  //your data CRUD operation logic goes here
  // for success return success response
 return new Response("sucess")
  // for failure or error return error response
return new Response("error")

}
```

write a groovy class to handle the response e.g Response.groovy

```
class Response {  
        boolean success  
        def errors = []           

        Response(String errorMessage) {  
            this.success = false  
            this.errors << [message: errorMessage]  
        }  
        ....  
    }
```

finally your gsp code looks like

```
 <g:javascript>
    function handleResponse(response,textStatus){
    if(response.success === true){
     //use the div and write the UI to show message
     } else {
     //use the div and write the UI to show message
     }    
    </g:javascript>
```

May be minor changes required to make it work but i am sure it fits for your need

Comment: I understand You've done. But is this the right way? So what is functionality of onFailure inside submitToRemote tag?